# Tipos de dados no SQL Server 2012 e formulários HTML com PHP: data e valores monetários

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, tipagem, sql-server-2012

Como eu posso colocar máscara num formulário HTML, nos campos de data e de valores monetários, depois enviar esses dados para o banco de dados sem precisar ficar convertendo as strings em tipos `date` e `money`?

Explico:

Eu possuo um formulário com máscara para data no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`, no entanto, meu banco dados (BD) SQL Server 2012 usa o formato `AAAA-MM-DD`. Quando submeto o formulário para o PHP fazer inserção no BD, os dados são enviados em forma de *string* (e.g.: '31/10/2012'), então, eu necessito fazer uma conversão:

```
$data = '31/10/2012';
$data_formatada = str_replace('/', '-', $data);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_formatada));
```

O outro caso é o dos dados do tipo money.

A máscara do formulário é `9.999.999.999.999,99` e o banco de dados possui o formato `999999999999.99`. Quando submeto o formulário pro PHP fazer a inserção, tenho que eliminar os pontos e substituir a vírgula por ponto para só depois fazer inserção dos dados no banco de dados.

Pergunta: existe forma mais eficiente de fazer inserção de data e valores monetários no banco de dados do que essas que eu descrevi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim existe uma forma mais prática de fazer isso, use as funções especializadas para isso, não trate a situação como um problema de formatação de texto.

Para datas use a classe DateTime, ela tem o método [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) que recebe uma data no formato deseja e retorna um objeto DateTime, use o método [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) para mudar o formato da data de `d/m/Y` para `Y-m-d`

```
$data =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2015');
echo $data->format('Y-m-d');
```

Para valores monetários use a biblioteca de internacionalização a Intl está disponível desde o php5.3, habilite ela pelo php.ini. [parseCurrency()](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php), recebe uma string em formato de moeda e remove todas as formatações. [formatCurrency()](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) faz o processo oposto a partir de um número devolve uma string com o valor moeda aplicado.

```
$arr=array('R$530.077,99','R$31.459,89','R$2.899,39','R$600,51','R$13,00','R$9,00','R$0,25');
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
foreach($arr as $item){
    echo  $formatter->parseCurrency($item, $valor_puro) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O SQL Server não possui formato algum, ele guarda dados, todos os banco de dados funcionam assim, formato é algo que a aplicação deve usar para apresentar o dado. Ele até pode ser a aplicação e usar um formato quando se faz uma *query*, mas armazenamento é outra coisa. Se for olhar lá no arquivo verá que nem é este formato que você acha que tem. Obviamente que se fizer uma *query* ele vai apresentar de alguma forma mais legível por um humano e isto é uma formato padrão, então já há uma conversão, e precisará fazer outra sempre que desejar um formato específico. Não tem como fugir disto.

O PHP possui algumas opções e você pode usar o que for mais conveniente. Mas não precisa se preocupar com eficiência. O que tem que ser feito, precisa ser feito. O custo é baixo e uma micro otimização sem sentido, especialmente em PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Usando HTML5, porém sem suporte para IE:

```
<input type="tel" required="required" maxlength="15" 
name="valor" pattern="([0-9]{1,3}\.)?[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{2}$" />
```

Comment: Não seria mais semântico `type='number'`?