# Centavos corretos nos boletos bancários da BoletoPHP

Tags: php, html, boleto, valor-monetário

Estou usando o projeto da BoletoPHP para gerar boletos bancários, porém reparei que os centavos não são gravados corretamente, pois quando compro um produto com o valor de por exemplo, R$ 245,00 mais a taxa bancária R$ 2,95, ele imprime corretamente o valor de R$ 247,95.

Mas quando compro um produto com o valor de 2.399,99 mais a taxa bancária de R$ 2,95, ele imprime o valor de R$ 2.401,95, quando o correto seria R$ 2.402,94.

Ou seja ele ignora os centavo dos produtos, mas não ignora os centavos da taxa bancária.

Os amigos poderiam me dizer onde estou errando, ou qual seria a solução para que ele imprima também os centavos dos produtos.

No Banco de Dados estou gravando na coluna como tipo "decimal(10,2)".

Abaixo relaciono o linha de código do boleto referente ao valor.

```
   $dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento = 5;
   $taxa_boleto = 2.95;
   $data_venc = date("d/m/Y", time() + (5 * 86400));  // Prazo de X dias OU informe data: "13/04/2006"; 
   $valor_cobrado = $_POST["total"]; // Valor - REGRA: Sem pontos na milhar e tanto faz com "." ou "," ou com 1 ou 2 ou sem casa decimal
   $valor_cobrado = str_replace(".", "",$valor_cobrado);
   $valor_boleto=number_format($valor_cobrado+$taxa_boleto,2,",",".");
```

Abaixo relaciono o linha de código do formulário referente ao valor.

```
   <?php
   if(count($_SESSION['carrinho']) == 0){
      echo '<tr><td colspan="5">Não há produto no carrinho</td></tr>';
   }else{
      require("conexao.php");
   $total = 0;
      foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $codigo => $qtd){
   $sql   = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo= '$codigo'";
   $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

   $titulo  = $ln['titulo'];
   $preco = number_format($ln['preco'], 2, ',', '.');
   $sub   = number_format($ln['preco'] * $qtd, 2, ',', '.');

   $total += $ln['preco'] * $qtd;

      echo '<tr style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">       
                <td  align="left">'.$titulo.'</td>
                <td align="center">'.$qtd.'</td>
                <td align="center">R$ '.$preco.'</td>
                <td align="center">R$ '.$sub.'</td>
                <td align="center"><a href="?acao=del&codigo='.$codigo.'">
                <img width="25" src="img/del.png" title="Remover '.$titulo.'"/>
                </a></td>
             </tr>';
    }
    $total = number_format($total, 2, ',', '.');
       echo '<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="right" style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#990000;" colspan="3">Total</td>
                <td align="left" style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;" colspan="4">R$ '.$total.'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

Como faço para que o boleto imprima os centavos dos produtos?

Comment: Pode formatar o valor moeda [assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102556/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o PHP, assim como todas as linguagens, não trabalha bem com valores monetários precisos.

Acho curioso que um programa pronto para trabalhar com valores monetários não lida bem com isto.

Tem [várias perguntas aqui sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valor-monet%C3%A1rio), mas até agora ninguém quis fazer uma específica para o PHP.

O processador trabalha muito bem com valores decimais mas para ter performance ele faz isto com base 2. Por isso não dá para representar com exatidão todos os valores.

A maioria dos programadores não sabem disso e causam problemas para os usuários dos seus softwares. A diferença pode ser de um centavo, mas se você multiplicar 1 centavo por 1 milhão, dá dez mil reais de prejuízo para um lado ou outro. Pode gerar processo judicial ou multa em fiscalização.

Então precisa tratar valores monetários de outra forma. O MySQL tem uma forma adequada, várias linguagens tem um tipo de dado que lida com o número de outra forma para evitar este problema da exatidão. Todo o tratamento deve ser feito em base 10. Em geral isto é feito com um número inteiro e escala para representar a parte decimal. Números inteiros não sofrem deste problema. Isto pode ser feito de forma transparente em muitas linguagens. Não é o caso do PHP.

A solução é fazer manual, ou criar um novo tipo de dado que encapsule esta lógica, ou usar algo pronto.

Manualmente é tratar os valores pelos centavos para todas contas e só na apresentação usar a vírgula. Se tratar os números pelos centavos, um inteiro resolve o problema. Em vez de ter 245,00 reais, você terá 24500 centavos.

Claro que tem que saber fazer algumas operações, como multiplicação e divisão para não dar problema de escala. Divisões e multiplicações por 100 serão comuns (partindo do princípio que há duas casas decimais).

Pra evitar ficar fazendo isto sempre e esquecer de algo, algumas pessoas encapsulam isto em uma classe `Decimal` ou `Money` abstraindo um pouco as operações e tornando o uso mais natural.

Existem algumas destas classes prontas. O próprio PHP tem um módulo adicional chamado [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php). Não gosto muito dela, mas é uma solução pronta.

Em qualquer caso a apresentação dos dados é diferente do dado em si. Não adianta resolver o problema da apresentação se os cálculos, que é o importante, continuam errados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

A conta feita pelo PHP está certa 2399 mais 2.95 é 2.401,95. Isso acontece porque ao transforma a string `2.399,99` em float o 99 dos centavos é descartado pois o separado de é `.` e não virgular.

Uma string em que o primeiro caracter seja um número, O PHP tratará isso como um número por isso a [expressão “2 + '6 maçãs'” é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/91)

```
$a = 10;
$b = (float)'20,1';

echo $a + $b;
```

O resultado esperado seria 30.1 certo? não!, apenas `20` é considerado um valor númerico, para o resultado esperado o valor deveria ser 20.1. Se o valor de `$b` fosse `20#%$99` e somado a `$a` a saida ainda seria `30`.

Simulação do erro:

```
$taxa_boleto = 2.95;
$valor_cobrado = '2.399,99';
$valor_cobrado =  str_replace(".", "", $valor_cobrado);
$res = $valor_cobrado + $taxa_boleto;
$valor_boleto = number_format($valor_cobrado + $taxa_boleto, 2, ",", ".");
```

A saida é 2401.95. A conta feita foi 2399 + 2.95

Solução do separador trocado de `,` por `.`

```
$taxa_boleto = 2.95;
$valor_cobrado = '2.399,99';
$valor_cobrado =  str_replace(".", "", $valor_cobrado);
$valor_cobrado =  str_replace(",", ".", $valor_cobrado); //linha adicionada
$res = $valor_cobrado + $taxa_boleto;
echo $res;
```

Saida: 2402.94. A conta feita foi 2399.99 + 2.95

Answer (score 2):

Olá, gostaria de agradecer ao rray pois com a sua dica consegui fazer com que o boleto imprima corretamente "(incluindo os centavos dos produtos)" os valores dos produtos somados ou não as taxas bancárias.

Eu alterei as seguintes linhas abaixo do código.

Ignorando  centavos dos produtos - Errado

```
 $valor_cobrado = str_replace(".", "",$valor_cobrado);
 $valor_boleto=number_format($valor_cobrado+$taxa_boleto,2,",",".");
```

Incluindo centavos dos Produtos - Correto

```
 $valor_cobrado = str_replace(",", "",$valor_cobrado);
 $valor_boleto=number_format($valor_cobrado+$taxa_boleto,2,".",".");
```

Testei em boletos dos bancos:
Banco do Brasil, Caixa Econômica, Itaú, Bradesco, Santander, e funcionou em todos.

Espero que ajude a outros usuários do BoletoPHP.

Valeu rray, e abraços à todos.

Comment: Quando trabalhar com valores monetários, defina o tipo da coluna do banco de dados como DECIMAL(20, 6), por exemplo. Isso permitirá maior precisão decimal. 

Um problema comum é que muitos programadores inexperientes confundem o formato visual de um valor monetário com o padrão matemático. Na matemática, não existe vírgula para identificar casa decimal ou milenar. O único identificador é o ponto (.), o qual indica valor fracionado.