# Regra no model usando str_replace() para substituir "," por "."

Tags: cakephp

A regra não está funcionando. Eu pego um valor em reais com a "," e quero substituir por "." para salvar os valores decimais no banco. Por exemplo, o valor 35,39 reais seria 35.39 no banco. A regra não funciona e o valor perde as casas decimais, só ficando com 35.00 no banco.

Controller:

```
<?php  

public function inserirDespesa() {  
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {  

//carrega model  
$this->loadModel('Despesa');  

if ($this->Despesa->save($this->request->data)) {  

$this->Session->setFlash("Despesa inserida");     
}  
}  

}  
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php  

class Despesa extends AppModel {  

    public $name='despesa';  
    public $useTable='despesas';  
    public $primaryKey='id_despesa';  

public $validate=array(  
'valor_despesa'=>array(  
'preco'=>array(  
'rule'=>'preco')));  

    public function preco($check) {  
$valorDespesa=0;  

$valorDespesa=str_replace(",", ".", $check['valor_despesa']);  

return true;  
}  

}  
?>
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Centavos corretos nos boletos bancários da BoletoPHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104193/91)

Answer (score 0):

O campo onde você insere esse valor deve estar configurado no `Mysql` como `float`, e  não como `int`.

Também é importante lembrar que nesse caso você está obtendo uma `string`, e não um valor `float`.

Tente dar um `cast` para `float` para ver se isso funciona:

```
$valorDespesa = (float) str_replace(",", ".", $check['valor_despesa']);
```

Comment: O problema é que o "," não é substituído por ",". O formato no banco é decimal