# Soma direto no PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um sistema de controle de serviços.
Gostaria de emitir um relatório de serviços e somar esses valores mas não queria fazer com o comando no `sql` quero fazer direto no `php`, tipo somar os valores da coluna `valor_trabalho` apenas dos serviços listados

seria tipo assim

```
OS | DESCRICAO | VALOR

 1 |  visita   | 150,00

 2 |  visita   | 130,00

total = ???
```

meu sql e assim

```
$trabalho=mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM cad_trabalho WHERE id_trabalho = '$id'");`
```

uso essa função para exibir os dados

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($trabalho)) {                                    
echo "<tr><td>$row->os</td><td>$row->descricao</td><td>$row->valor</td></tr>
      <tr>total = ???</tr>";
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo simples:

```
<?php
   $total = 0;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_object($trabalho)) {                                    
      $total += $row->valor;
      echo "<tr><td>$row->os</td><td>$row->descricao</td><td>$row->valor</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "<tr><td colspan="3">TOTAL: $total</td></tr>";
?>
```

Isto é claro, supondo que `$rou->valor` seja numérico. Se for *string*, depende do formato. Pode ser necessário trocar vírgula por ponto, etc.

Só pra constar, `$total += $row->valor` é o jeito curto de escrever `$total = $total + $row->valor`

Comment: funcionou perfeito

agora so estou tendo erro com o valor que esta me resultando R$: 89978.856 pois meus valores salvos sao tipo 350,66 1.253,00

Comment: É basicamente o que eu comentei, seus valores estão armazenados no formato errado, estão gravados como string no DB. O certo é gravar em numérico, e por as vírgulas e pontos na tela só na exibição. Como já estão gravados errados, teria que usar `$total += strtr( strtr( $valor, '.', '' ), ',', '.' );` - Mas isso é uma gambiarra sofrida. O certo é consertar o erro, em vez de usar um remendo.

Comment: tem alguma função para corrigir no bd?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, teria que fazer um backup do DB pra evitar acidentes. Depois, tirar os pontos, depois trocar as vírgulas por ponto, e converter a tabela pra decimal. Se for um projeto novo, e os dados forem apenas teste, não precisa ter esse trabalho todo, basta recriar a tabela com o campo do valor ou em inteiros (e armazenar o valor em centavos, pra não precisar do ponto), ou usar o tipo DECIMAL, que é para valores financeiros.

Comment: Aqui tem uma resposta que fala um pouco disso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104203/70

Comment: Ja tem mais de 1000 registros :)

Comment: Gostaria que me ajudasse em mais um ponto aqui

Comment: Meu resultado esta me trazendo o seguinte valor  `R$: 237688.6`como faço para que exiba `R$: 237688.60`