# Duvidas na função float do PHP

Tags: php, html5, php-7

```
$valorBaixa  = (float)$this->input->post('valorBaixa');
```

Eu tenho essa função float aonde a mesma transformar um string em valor float, so que a mesma esta cortando os valores. Exemplo:

se for digitado "8,75"
a função converte em 8

aonde era pra converter em 8,75.

Comment: Na verdade este código está cometendo um grave erro e muitos programadores não se dão conta disto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104193/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, respondendo sua pergunta:

Números de ponto flutuante (também conhecidos como "floats", "doubles" ou "números reais"), podem ser especificados utilizando qualquer uma das seguintes sintaxes:

```
<?php
$a = 1.234;
$b = 1.2e3;
$c = 7E-10;
?>
```

> Para informações sobre a conversão de strings para float, veja a seção [Conversão de Strings para números](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Para valores de outros tipos, o valor é primeiro convertido para inteiro e então para float. Veja a seção [Convertendo para inteiros](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) para mais informações. No PHP 5, um aviso é emitido se você tentar converter um object para um float.

Referência: [manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php).

O que você está fazendo é um `parsing` do tipo `string` para `float`, recomendo que dê uma olhada nos links acima, que são da documentação do PHP para melhor entendimento.

Você pode fazer assim:

```php
<?php

function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos : 
        ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);

    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    } 

    return floatval(
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . '.' .
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep+1, strlen($num)))
    );
}
```

E utilizar assim:

`$valorBaixa  = tofloat($this->input->post('valorBaixa'));`

Explicando:

Foi criada uma função para que seja tratado a substituição da vírgula, que é o que está acontecendo no seu caso(pois o float utiliza o ponto para separação dos valores decimais).

Outros exemplos:

```
$numero = 'R$ 1.545,37';
var_dump(tofloat($numero));
```

output:
`float(1545.37)`

Referência: [manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php)